# Changing XWindow geometry

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, x11, ctypes

I have two programs, first's got a XWindow and I get its xid, then in the second one I want to do some operations (eg changing size, position, etc..) on that window (xid as a XWindow). I use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) for Python3. The funfact is that `XResizeWindow(display, xid, 320, 240)` returns..yes..1, but of course the window geometry is the same as before.

```
xid = 2675429 #windowid..
X = cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6")

display = X.XOpenDisplay(None)
if display == 0:
    sys.exit("Cannot open display.")

X.XResizeWindow(display, xid, 320, 240)
X.XCloseDisplay(display)
```

Comment: add XFlush() before close?

Comment: Wow, now works. Thanks! Btw I'm gonna post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Andrey Sidorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/705115/andrey-sidorov) said I have to call **XFlush()** before display closing. Now works.

Comment: xlib buffers outgoing requests, so without xflush you basically connect to X, add some bytes to a buffer and exit (without sending anything). Also for some requests (like PolyPoint) instead of adding extra request xlib appends data (point) to previous request array of points thus saving some overhead